# Magento Cannot Initialize Index Process (No Locks Folder in Var)

Tags: reindex, magento-1.9.2.1

**The issue:**

When I try and reindex my local site, I get the error that Magento "cannot initialize the indexer process."

**Other information:**

- Upon trying to manually reindex the files through the terminal, I was made aware that pdo_mysql has not been installed.

- It is the "Product Flat Data" that needs to be reindexed.

- The problem is occurring on both the local and live copies of the site.

- This problem  does not occur on other local copies of sites I work on.

- I do not have a "locks" folder in my /var folder.

Also, if it is important I have Magento 1.9.2.1 installed, am running through PhpStorm, am on a Mac, I run my local sites through MAMP.

Please help!

Comment: Entire Magento will fall if pdo_mysql was not installed. What commands did you run when you tried indexing from terminal. Also, check permissions on var folder.

Comment: Magento automatically creates the var/locks/ folder, unless the ownership/permissions on var/ are not allowing it.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it programmatically. This way:

```
$indexCollection = Mage::getModel('index/process')->getCollection();
    foreach ($indexCollection as $index) {
      $index->reindexAll();
  }
```